# factory, unique_ptr and static_cast

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider polymorphic classes with a base object, a derived interface, and a final object:

```
// base object

struct object
{
    virtual ~object() = default;
};

// interfaces derived from base object

struct interface1 : object
{
    virtual void print_hello() const = 0;

    template<typename T>
    static void on_destruction(object* /*ptr*/)
    {
        std::cout << "interface1::on_destruction" << std::endl;
    }
};

// final object

struct derived1 : interface1
{
    virtual void print_hello() const override
    {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }

    static std::string get_type_name()
    {
        return "derived1";
    }
};
```

In the real use case, final objects are defined through a plugin system, but that is not the point. Note that I want to be able to call `on_destruction` when an object is destroyed (see `register_object` below). I want to use these classes as follows:

```
int main()
{
    // register derived1 as an instantiable object,
    // may be called in a plugin

    register_object<derived1>();

    // create an instance using the factory system

    auto instance = create_unique<interface1>("derived1");
    instance->print_hello();

    return 0;
}
```

Using std::unique_ptr to manage the objects, I ended up with the following code for `register_object`:

```
template<typename T>
using unique = std::unique_ptr<
    T,
    std::function<void(object*)> // object deleter
>;

namespace
{
    std::map< std::string, std::function<unique<object>(void)> > factory_map;
}

template<typename T>
void register_object()
{
    factory_map.emplace(
        T::get_type_name(),
        []()
        {
            unique<T> instance{
                new T,
                [](object* ptr)
                {
                    T::on_destruction<T>(ptr);

                    delete ptr;
                }
            };

            return static_move_cast<object>(
                std::move(instance)
            );
        }
    );
}
```

And the `create`* functions:

```
unique<object> create_unique_object(const std::string& type_name)
{
    auto f = factory_map.at(type_name);
    return f();
}

template<typename T>
unique<T> create_unique(const std::string& type_name)
{
    return static_move_cast<T>(
        create_unique_object(type_name)
    );
}
```

You noticed in `register_object` and `create_unique` the call to `static_move_cast`, which is declared as:

```
template<typename U, typename T, typename D>
std::unique_ptr<U, D>
static_move_cast
(
    std::unique_ptr<T, D>&& to_move_cast
)
{
    auto deleter = to_move_cast.get_deleter();

    return std::unique_ptr<U, D>{
        static_cast<U*>(
            to_move_cast.release()
        ),
        deleter
    };
}
```

The goal behind `static_move_cast` is to allow static_cast on std::unique_ptr while moving the deleter during the cast. The code is working, but I feel like hacking std::unique_ptr. Is there a way to refactor the code to avoid my `static_move_cast`?

Comment: Ew, `object` bases

Comment: If you wish to reuse your `static_move_cast` in other places, you may want to add a separate template function for cases where `std::default_delete<T>` is used (the version you use right now will work with them but will produce an object of undesirable type - std::unique_ptr<Base> will be converted to std::unique_ptr<Derived, std::default_delete<Base>> which is really awkward). [Here](https://gist.github.com/SergNikitin/9b55f4400111742dac1e2cf9ea7206bc) you can find a version of it that I wrote not long ago for myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static_move_cast` is unnecessary within `register_object`, since you can just use the [converting constructor of `unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) `template< class U, class E > unique_ptr( unique_ptr<U, E>&& u )`:

```
        unique<T> instance{
            new T,
            // ...
        };

        return instance;
```

Or, even simpler, construct and return a `unique<object>` directly, since `T*` is convertible to `object*`:

```
        return unique<object>{
            new T,
            // ...
        };
```

However for `create_unique` the use of `static_move_cast` is unavoidable, since the converting constructor of `unique_ptr` won't work for downcasts.

Note that `shared_ptr` has [`static_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast), which performs downcasts, but there is no corresponding facility for `unique_ptr`, presumably because it it is considered straightforward and correct to perform the cast yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is good solution given the requirements. You transfer the responsibility to the caller of `create_unique`. He must give correct combination of type and string and string that is in the registry.

```
auto instance = create_unique<interface1>("derived1");
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^
//                         what if those two don't match?
```

You could improve it a bit by changing the `static_cast` to `dynamic_cast`. And the caller of `create_unique` should always check that he got non-null pointer before calling anything on it.

Or at least use `dynamic_cast` with `assert` in debug mode, so you catch mismatches while developing.

---

Alternative refactoring: Have separate factory for every existing interface.